# Does Intellij Support Standalone Gorm with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, intellij-idea, grails-orm

Does IntelliJ Support Standalone Gorm? In the sense that it offers method completion for domain objects. There is a lot of information out there that says it has been implemented, however, as of March 29, 2017 on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160166) it appears that it is still unavailable.

[Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/13.0/grails.pdf) for IntelliJ 13  also explicitly states that GORM standalone is supported, however, it does not seem to work when configured with Spring Boot.

It was also supposedly released with IntelliJ 16.

So has anyone gotten it to work? What do you need to do to configure your project to support standalone gorm?

Answer (score 2):

> Does IntelliJ Support Standalone Gorm?

Yes.

> So has anyone gotten it to work?

Yes.  Nothing special is required to do that.  As an example, open the project at https://github.com/grails-samples/gorm-outside-grails in IntelliJ IDEA.  That isn't a boot app, but if it were, the relevant behavior still works the same way.  To see auto-completion in action, edit the file at https://github.com/grails-samples/gorm-outside-grails/blob/d56e56bc12b2ba9732449fd6779ae0ac0e487ec2/src/test/groovy/domain/PersonSpec.groovy and see the autocompletion you get behind `p.<method name goes here>`.  You get completion for all the normal GORM methods like `attach`, `discard`, `hasErrors` etc.  You also get auto completion for things like dynamic finders.  It all works quite well.